# cordova facebook connect plugin - Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I have used following code in my app

for browser

```
// Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
// Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
// contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
// Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
(function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document, /*debug*/ false));

FB.init(
                    {
                        appId: fbid,
    //                  nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
                        cookie:true,
                        status:true,
                        xfbml:true
                    });
```

Its working perfectly in browser.

Then after  for my phonegap app I have referred `https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin` for login with facebook functionality. I have added "`cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js`" and "`facebook-js-sdk.js`" files in my index.html

And I have commented above dynamic javascript SDK code. For login I used

```
FB.init(
                {
                    appId: fbid,
//                  nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
                    cookie:true,
                    status:true,
                    xfbml:true
                });
```

But In emulator I am getting error as `Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.` So can you please suggest to resolve this issue.